# How to assign state value into string variable in Angural Component [ngrx Store]

Tags: angular, ngrx-store

This is my code. But It gives error.

```
public productKey: string;

    constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {
      this.productKey = store.pipe(select('product'), map((productState: ProductState) => productState.productKey));
    }
```

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: Type 'Observable<string>' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts

Comment: cause your productKey assignment return Observable which need to subscribe to assign to local productKey property or use Observable<string> type and use g.e. async pipe.

Comment: I need to assign productKey state to my local variable. Not to Observable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Expresion:

```
store.pipe(select('product'), map((productState: ProductState) => productState.productKey))
```

return a Observable with string type (Observable). To assign value from the store to the local variable you need to subscribe it:

```
store
  .pipe(select('product'), map((productState: ProductState) => productState.productKey))
  .subscribe(value => this.productKey = value);
```

If you use it in your HTML, the better solution is to assign Observable to the variable and extract value directly inside template using [Async Pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe).